# Setting a seed with dbplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, dbplyr

To sample from a database table I frequently use the pattern

```
library(dplyr)

tbl(con, 'tableName') %>%
  mutate(z = random()) %>%
  compute() %>%
  arrange(z) %>%
  filter(row_number() < numSamples) %>%
  collect()
```

Is there a way to set the seed so that the sample can be replicated?

Comment: Could you add what libraries are loaded, where is the `random()` from? Did you try: `set.seed(123); tbl(con, ....)` ?

Comment: `random()` is a PostgreSQL/Redshift function that gets evaluated on the database side. Setting the seed with `set.seed()` on the R side doesn't work. If I were working in SQL directly I would just run `set seed to 0.5` before running the query

Comment: dirty way to do this would be to extract the query with `dbplyr::translate_sql()`, then execute `paste("set seed to 0.5;", query)`